# Image Not Staying Within Parent Div

Tags: css, image, padding, image-resizing

I am trying to make some responsive cards. I have the cards completed and spaced out properly. On the front of the cards I want an image on the top of the cards and a title in the middle. The title is fine and the image is fine except for the right side of the image.
Here is the CSS code for the image (image is in an img tag in HTML page with a class of "image"):

```
div .image {
    padding: 5%;
    height: 45%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The right side for some reason is ignoring the padding and sticking out of the card parent div. Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you provide your code or an example that reproduce what you're trying to do?
(with a code snippet, that would be great). I would also advise you to read the rules/advices on how to post a good question on StackO.

Comment: You’ve set the width 100% and then added padding so altogether it is too wide. Have a look into object-fit contain or box-sizing: border-box.

Answer (score 1):

You set the width to be 100% and padding 5%. Make sure you have:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

for the parent.
Also without the full example of code, hard to answer. Can use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent to hide that part sticking out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I tried that and it didn't work, but I ended up finding the solution. It was keeping the same height and width percentages and adding max-height and max-width values.

Answer (score 0):

did you already set `div`'s `width`?
also as far i know is no need to set image's `height` if you already set it's `width` to `100%` 
anyway here some example

```
div { width: 200px; height: 150px; padding: 6px; }
div img { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, adding max-width and max-height to the styling along with the width and height solved the problem for me